# Image uploading not working in server

Tags: media

In a content type have a field image upload.its image upload type is jpg,png,gif.
When we upload these image type of images an error is coming :

> The selected file Chrysanthemum.jpg could not be uploaded. The file is
>   not a known image format.

But its running in local not in server. What is the problem ?
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below are the two ways. I hope help you to solve your issue.

***1.*** 
Your files via FTP into the `image_import` directory aren't being given the correct permissions. You have to provide the permission i.e. `chmod 660 *` on them in the `image_import` directory the files were recognized correctly and the import worked.

**OR**

***2.***
In **/includes/image.inc**, change line 117 from:

```
  if (!is_file($file)) {
```

to:

```
if (!is_file($file) && !is_uploaded_file($file)) {
```

Then check is your issue is solved or not. If not then try once updating below with second way :

On the `admin/settings/file-system`, try changing `C:\WINDOWS\Temp` to `sites/default/files/temp` (also made sure it was writeable by the web server).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with other images? Do you get the same error with other .jpg files? Or .gif files? Perhaps Chrysanthemum.jpg is a corrupt file.

Can you upload other files? Are /tmp permissions set correctly?

If so, it could be a PHP issue, and not a Drupal issue. Check whether the FileInfo module is installed:

```
pecl install fileinfo
```

Or if you run Apache, check if the `libjpeg.so` module is enabled.

Comment: i tried but got same error.

Comment: I amended my answer with more detail, see if that helps.